# EzApi Issue with Excel Connection Manager

Tags: excel, reflection, ssis, window, ezapi

EzApi is used to create SSIS package, package reads excel file through oledb connection manager(microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0) When i create EzExecSQLTask object after dataflow that reads the excel file,

i got the exception : `object does not match the target type`

After Debugging the EzApi code i found below line is generating the exception

`host.Properties["TimeOut"].SetValue(host, value);`

it seemed that when the property is set through reflection it doesn't find the target object.

Code works fine on widows xp machine , but on windows Server 2012 its causing the issue.

**stack trace**

```
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ManagedHelper.ManagedPropertyHelper.SetPropertyValue(Object o, Int32 index, Object value)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsProperty.SetValue(Object o, Object value)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.SSIS.EzAPI.EzExecSqlTask.set_TimeOut(UInt32 value) in d:\ROI_ETL\ROi\ETL\Optime.ISS.ETL.EzApi\EzExecutables.cs:line 751
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.SSIS.EzAPI.EzExecSqlTask.InitializeTask() in d:\ROI_ETL\ROi\ETL\Optime.ISS.ETL.EzApi\EzExecutables.cs:line 740
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.SSIS.EzAPI.EzExecSqlTask..ctor(EzContainer parent) in d:\ROI_ETL\ROi\ETL\Optime.ISS.ETL.EzApi\EzExecutables.cs:line 732
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.SSIS.EzAPI.Common.ComponentWrapper.CreateSQLTaskWithExpression(EzContainer p, String name, String sql, EzConnectionManager cm) in d:\ROI_ETL\ROi\ETL\Optime.ISS.ETL.EzApi\Common\ComponentWrapper.cs:line 55
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.SSIS.EzAPI.SSI_Wrapper.SSIPackage.LogMessage(String stepID, String stepName, String userID, String statusID, String message, String sqlTaskName, EzExecutable attachToComp, EzConnectionManager cm) in d:\ROI_ETL\ROi\ETL\Optime.ISS.ETL.EzApi\SSI Wrapper\SSIPackage.cs:line 723
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.SSIS.EzAPI.SSI_Wrapper.SSIPackage.CreatePackage(Int64 userID, Nullable`1 sourceID, Int64 taskID, Boolean isSystemTask, StepDTO step, List`1 execStatus) in d:\ROI_ETL\ROi\ETL\Optime.ISS.ETL.EzApi\SSI Wrapper\SSIPackage.cs:line 178
   at Optime.ISS.ETL.WebAPI.SSISPackageController.ExecuteTask(TaskDTO task) in d:\ROI_ETL\ROi\ETL\Optime.ISS.ETL.WebAPI\SSISPackageController.cs:line 77
```

**More Information**

Issue occured only on windows server 2012 when microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 is used to connect to excel file. Same  code works fine in window xp with microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 32 bit drivers

please help.... we can move any further.

please suggest right forum.